# autocompletion of .. from a symlinked path

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Say I `cd` to a symlink then try to tab-autocomplete on top of `../`

```
$ mkdir /foo/bar
$ ln -s /foo/bar /baz/bar
$ cd /baz
$ cd bar
$ cd ../{tab}
```

In bash, autocomplete presents me with the contents of `baz`, the logical parent.

In zsh, autocomplete gives the contents of `foo`, the physical parent.

Is it possible to get the bash style `..` autocomplete resolution in zsh?  In other words, autocomplete should traverse the directory stack before the physical structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the answer about how to do it is *upgrade your Zsh to 5.0.5*. See this bug case http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2013/msg00736.html